# Prove that a function is k homogenous

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
Given that $F: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $ is differentiable and
$\forall (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 :xf_x(x,y)+yf_y(x,y)=kf(x,y)$
Prove that f is homogenous of k'th degree for some k>0.

**Thoughts**:
We've managed to show that using a composition with the function $h(t)=(tx,ty) $s.t
$g=f \circ h$ then $g(t)=\frac tk g'(t)$

Comment: You should show that $f(tx,ty)=t^kf(x,y)$

Comment: We know that. But how? :-)

Comment: This is Euler's theorem. I think posting it as an answer is not good because you can find it easily. :-)

Comment: We haven't studied Euler's theorem. so maybe a hint? thx

Comment: See [this](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/EulerHomogeneity.pdf). Easy to understand.

Comment: We read this now. The problem is we haven't studied differential equations yet. Is there any way to prove it without using these theorems?

Comment: See [this ](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/439275/8581), but I don't think we can overcome the problem without using an ODE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, you are really close.

Just integrate both parts, you get that 
$$ \int \frac{g'(t)}{g(t)}\, \mathrm{d}t = \int \frac{k}{t}\, \mathrm{d}t$$

$$ ln(g(t)) = ln(t^{k}) $$

$$ f(tx,ty) = t^{k} $$

for  $t=1$ we get $ f(x,y) = 1 $

therefore
$$ f(tx,ty) = t^{k} f(x,y) $$